# Angular component is missing a template

Tags: angular, angular9

I am upgrading an app from Angular 8 to Angular 9 and have the following error when I do a build:

`ERROR in component is missing a template`

There is no indication of which component is missing a template. Is there a way to find this out without going into each component individually?

I have been through all the components in the app and they all seem to have an `templateUrl` specified in the `@Component` decorator. Here is an example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-activities',
  templateUrl: './activities.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activities.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: You can search in your editor with a Regex

Comment: @Angular thanks for that although I am hoping that there is a more sophisticated approach (aside from the problems of using regex to not find something). This seems like a particularly obscure error message and I am wondering if there is a reason it does not reference the component it is complaining about.

Comment: If you are sure all the components owns a templateUrl provide a reproduction

Comment: @Angular I have added an example to the question but I don't see what benefit there is in that. Have templateUrls changed between Angular 8 and 9?

Comment: @MikePoole Thats not reproduction - its just snippet - and yes, no gain from it.

Comment: @Antoniossss yes I am aware that it is a snippet. I am not sure what repo you guys are after. Are you wanting to see the whole codebase?

Comment: Anything that will allow to reproduce your error - so somebody can find fix for that.

Comment: @Antoniossss it is not always possible to share the entire codebase (this is a commercial project). Have you worked with Angular 9 yet and if so have you come across this cryptic error message?

Comment: Its obvious that you wont be able to share whole codebase - but yet, no reproduceable example = hard to find solution. And the loophole is closed.

Comment: @Antoniossss which part of the code do you want me to reproduce? I am not looking for a loophole, I am looking for someone that has come across this new error in Angular 9. Have you come across it before?

Comment: *which part of the code do you want me to reproduce?* What? Please read carefully this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as I have feeling we are on very different pages here.

Comment: @Antoniossss I know what an MVR example is but not everything is about providing a minimum viable. I am assuming you have not come across this compilation message in Angular 9 before (or have perhaps not used the Angular 9 RC yet) so unless you can tell me what code you expect when my question is about which code it affects then it'd be best to stop insisting on a repo.

Comment: *but not everything is about providing a minimum viable.* Yes it is, its the fastest way to get solution - especially if there is nothing obvious (which is this case) that cen be deducted from error message or short snippet. You are out of luck since nobody can try to actually solve the problem. Its almost like denying that reproducible example can help finding the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obscure error message is a bug with the Angular 9 release candidate which they are investigating:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34725

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just use a blank template, at least that's what worked for me.

```
template: ''
```